# seelect mutltiple elements xslt in apply-templates

Tags: xslt

I would like to select multiple elements at the same time, but the syntax is not correct

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./object[impact/product!='AA'|'BB']">

    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

whereas the sytax

```
    <xsl:apply-templates select="./object[impact/product!='AA']">

    </xsl:apply-templates>
```

did work.

apparently, the | does not work or I did a mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're trying to say:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="object[impact/product!='AA'] | object[impact/product!='BB']"/>
```

But of course this will apply templates to ALL objects that have a product, since if a product is equal to "AA", then it is not equal to "BB" and vice versa. You *probably* want to select:

```
object[impact/product!='AA' and impact/product!='BB']
```

or (more likely):

```
object[not(impact/product='AA' or impact/product='BB')]
```

Comment: thanks, the solution object[not(impact/product='AA' or impact/product='BB')] has worked for me ! it was helpful !